# Send file SFTP on Windows, PowerShell 2.0?

Tags: powershell, cmd, sftp

I need to automate a process that sends a file to a server via SFTP.

The server environment where I need to implement this is not very up-to-date and the PowerShell version is 2.0; my understanding is that therefore PostSSH is not supported, and also that a simple Windows command cannot support an SFTP transfer directly. I suspect it would be an extremely large, time consuming headache to update these programs on the server, and I'm supposed to get this script working yesterday...

I was also asked to do this without needing to install additional software (WinSCP).

Is there any way I can send a file via SFTP using .bat or old versions of PowerShell, that don't require new software of user interaction of any kind? How were these things done on old software?

Comment: WinSCP does no need to be installed. You can just drop its executables to any directory you have an access to.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - ",,,drop its executables to any directory..." is putting software from outside onto the machine. I am not questioning the goodness of WinSCP. Organizations have their requirements.

Comment: It appears that this cannot be done without putting something new on the machine. If something new is put on the machine, how about putting a modern-day PowerShell version on it?

Comment: "putting software from outside" != "install additional software". ("Install" implies running an installer.)

Comment: These are all fair points and help me understand my limitations and also my options.  I suppose even if I "wrote" code myself that happens to be what WinSCP is, then I wouldn't call it "installing new software." But on the other hand, I am introducing new code from outside the system that I didn't write myself...which is sometimes fine given that I "google" search code snippets all the time. I think this is best answered by how well I intimately understand the code before I implement it...? Bit of an existential question there :) Still, all helpful! Thanks

Comment: @PBJ - In many organizations, putting an executable file on the machine from outside is not permitted. Some allow source code from outside to be used, but some do not. Small source code files, often interpreted code such as .bat scripts, PowerShell, Python, Perl, etc., are permitted if the functionality and risks are well understood. Something complex enough to do SFTP will not be easily or quickly fully understood.

Comment: @lit The official download site for PuTTY + PuTTYgen is https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html -- Please consider removing and reposting your comment with the official link to avoid promoting an unrelated commercial website abusing a well know software.